How to resolve SyntaxError with react-native-fs in Metro bundler?
I am working on a React Native project and using react-native-fs。 However, when I run the project, I encounter the following SyntaxError:  and also react-native-blob-util show the same problem.
`ERROR  SyntaxError: C:\Users\70720\Desktop\zyrtworks\zy138rn76\node_modules\react-native-fs\FS.common.js: Unexpected token (42:9)
40 |
41 | type ReadDirItem = {

42 |   ctime: ?Date;    // The creation date of the file (iOS only)
|          ^
43 |   mtime: ?Date;    // The last modified date of the file
44 |   name: string;     // The name of the item
45 | p;   lute path to the item

My Current Configuration
babel.config.js
console.log('Babel config loaded');
module.exports = {
  presets:
    process.env.BABEL_ENV === 'app'
      ? ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset']
      : [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          '@babel/preset-react',
          '@babel/preset-typescript',
        ],
  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-typescript',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
    [
      require.resolve('babel-plugin-module-resolver'),

      {
        extensions: [
          '.js',
          '.jsx',
          '.ts',
          '.tsx',
          '.android.js',
          '.android.tsx',
          '.ios.js',
          '.ios.tsx',
        ],
        root: ['.'],
        alias: {
          src: './src/',
          lib: './src/lib/',
          components: './src/components/',
          '@api': './src/api/',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      test: /node_modules[/\\](react-native-fs|react-native-blob-util)[/\\].*/, // Specific modules
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types'],
    },
  ],
  env: {
    production: {},
  },
};


metro.config.js
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');
const {
  wrapWithReanimatedMetroConfig,
} = require('react-native-reanimated/metro-config');
// const { withNativeWind } = require('nativewind/metro');
module.exports = function (baseConfig) {
  const defaultConfig = mergeConfig(baseConfig, getDefaultConfig(__dirname));
  const {
    resolver: { assetExts, sourceExts },
  } = defaultConfig;
  const config = mergeConfig(defaultConfig, {
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg', 'js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    },
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
    },
  });

  return wrapWithReanimatedMetroConfig(config);
};


